# Mass Retry policy for connections to Azure service bus where Retry policy configured doesn’t work in case of Service Bus Connection Exception

Tags: azure, service, masstransit

Mass Retry policy for connections to Azure service bus where Retry policy configured doesn’t work in case of Service Bus Connection Exception

I have created console app which uses Mass Transit with Azure service bus where I have configured retry policy with following code.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GreenPipes;
using MassTransit;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;

namespace MassTransitRetryExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host("My Service Bus Connection string");
                cfg.UseRetry(retryConfig =>
                {
                 
                     retryConfig.Exponential(6, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("testqueue", ep =>
                {
                    
                    ep.Consumer<YourMessageConsumer>();
                });
            });

            await busControl.StartAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Sending a message...");
            await busControl.Publish(new YourMessage { Text = "Hello, World!" });

            //var publishEndpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:testqueue"));
            //await RetryPublish(publishEndpoint, new YourMessage { Text = "Hello, World!" });

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop receiving messages.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            await busControl.StopAsync();
        }
    }
```

If we provide wrong connection string of service bus to fail connection. It throws below exception and retries 4 times instead of 6 attempts since I configured retry policy set to exponential and count as 6. However, it retried 4 attempts only so can someone help me to know why it is not using the retry policy configuration from the code and where this retry count 4 comes from.

> System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (No such host is known. (my-bus.servicebus.windows.net:443)) (No such host is known. (my-bus.servicebus.windows.net:443)) (No such host is known. (my-bus.servicebus.windows.net:443)) (No such host is known. (my-bus.servicebus.windows.net:443))
>
> Azure.RequestFailedException: No such host is known. (my-bus.servicebus.windows.net:443)
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known. (my-bus.servicebus.windows.net:443)
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Versions used :

- Masstrasit version - 7.3.0
- MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core - 7.3.0**

I configured retry policy as below

```
cfg.UseRetry(retryConfig =>
                {
                     retryConfig.Exponential(6, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The retry policy used to connect to Azure Service Bus is not a developer-configurable policy. It will always retry using the internal policy until the cancellationToken passed to `StartAsync` is canceled.

Comment: Thank you for reply. is there anyway to override this

Comment: As stated in the answer, it is _not_ developer configurable.